# Intent.ACTION_SEND Whatsapp

Tags: android, stream, android-intent, share, send

Im trying to share a mp3 file through whatsapp. It works perfectly with other apps like gmail, but it dosent works on whatsapp. Can anyone help me? Do I need to add some putExtra()?

Here's my code:

```
public void shareWithFriends(int id)
{       
  Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  share.setType("audio/mp3");
  //share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject");
  //Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.igs.pokemonsoundboard/" + id);
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.igs.pokemonsoundboard/raw/" + R.raw.pikachump3);
  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
  //share.putExtra("sms_body","Ringtone File :");
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share sound"));
}
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should copy your audio file to sdcard, and share it as file, not as android resource, like this:

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_sound)));
```

Now it should work through whatsapp.

Comment: This code is not working for me, I'm getting the `Failed to send, please try again` message, even though I have saved the file in `sdcard`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the MIME type to "audio/mpeg3" so that the second line reads

```
share.setType("audio/mpeg3")
```

Comment: Thanks onielse14, but It dosent works. I try to change the type to mpeg3 without success. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp also accepts OGG format:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("audio/ogg");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getSoundUri());
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Include this in you code:

```
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```